# Cross compilers which generate idiomatic code

Tags: cross-compiling, code-generation, haxe

Looking for recommendations for a cross-compiler which generates idiomatic code. The use case being code examples for and open source project, however currently these need to be written in many different languages duplicating effort. The idea is that users of the library should be able to look at the generated code and "feel at home".

I checked out Haxe for this purpose, but didn't get the results I need. For example, this code:

```
class HelloWorld {
    static public function main() {
        trace("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Generates a pretty poor IDE experience for the end user:

```
@SuppressWarnings(value={"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public class HelloWorld extends haxe.lang.HxObject
{
        public HelloWorld(haxe.lang.EmptyObject empty)
        {
        }


        public HelloWorld()
        {
                //line 1 "/usr/local/google/home/nbirnie/git/test/HelloWorld.hx"
                haxe.root.HelloWorld.__hx_ctor__HelloWorld(this);
        }


        public static void __hx_ctor__HelloWorld(haxe.root.HelloWorld __hx_this)
        {
        }


        public static void main()
        {
                //line 3 "/usr/local/google/home/nbirnie/git/test/HelloWorld.hx"
                haxe.Log.trace.__hx_invoke2_o(0.0, "Hello World", 0.0, new haxe.lang.DynamicObject(new java.lang.String[]{"className", "fileName", "methodName"}, new java.lang.Object[]{"HelloWorld", "HelloWorld.hx", "main"}, new java.lang.String[]{"lineNumber"}, new double[]{((double) (((double) (3) )) )}));
        }           

}
```

There's always the option of writing a Domain Specific Language for this - the actual volume of generated code will be quite small, maybe 100 lines per class, with no coupling between classes. But thought I'd look for off the shelf solutions first.

Answer (score 2):

The output quality of Haxe depends per language backend (to have consistent behavior across all backends), but can always be improved. When you compile it to JavaScript it does get this "I'm home" feeling.

```
class HelloWorld {
    static public function main() {
        trace("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Results:

```js
(function () { "use strict";
var HelloWorld = function() { };
HelloWorld.main = function() {
    console.log("Hello World");
};
HelloWorld.main();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `@:nativeGen` and a platform-specific print function (instead of Haxe-specific one that needs position information) is generally a good start,

```
@:nativeGen class Main {
    static function main() {
        cs.system.Console.WriteLine("hi!");
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Main {

    public Main() {
    }


    public static void main() {
        global::System.Console.WriteLine(((string) ("hi!") ));
    }


}
```

As it is already mentioned, verbosity varies per platform - e.g. Haxe->JS or Haxe->AS3 produces pretty handwritten-looking code, while Haxe->C# and Haxe->C++ include a lot of implicit casts to eliminate any risk of code ambiguity.

It is possible to use Haxe's CustomJSGenerator API to write custom generators for non-JS languages (and transform code to match conventions/verbosity) - for example, I made a [Haxe->GML](https://yellowafterlife.itch.io/gamemaker-haxe) (a scripting language resembling a mix of flat C and JS) generator this way, and was able to have it match original structure pretty closely:
[image: idiomatic output with Haxe->GML]